# Owncloud 8 with Docker behind nginx available through subdirectory

Tags: nginx, docker, proxypass, owncloud

I want to run severel services/pages behind nginx. Each service shall be available through a subdirectory instead of a subdomain.

I'am using jwilder/nginx-proxy as proxy container:

```
nginx_proxy:
  image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
  container_name: nginx-proxy
  ports:
    - 80:80
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
```

And the owncloud container:

```
web:
  image: owncloud:8.1
  container_name: my_owncloud
  environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=www.example.com
  ports:
    - 8081:80
```

The modified nginx config:

```
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Proto, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# scheme used to connect to this server
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto {
  default $http_x_forwarded_proto;
  ''      $scheme;
}
# If we receive Upgrade, set Connection to "upgrade"; otherwise, delete any
# Connection header that may have been passed to this server
map $http_upgrade $proxy_connection {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
log_format vhost '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
access_log off;

# HTTP 1.1 support
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;

upstream cloud {
        server 172.17.0.3:80:
}
server {
        server_name domain.org www.domain.org;
        listen 80;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        root /var/www/main;

        location /cloud/ {
                proxy_pass http://cloud/;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://www.some-domain.com/;
        }

        location /sub/ {
                alias /var/www/sub/;
        }

}
```

The problem is that owncloud tries to load styles, images, etc. from / instead of /cloud. Owncloud itself is working and is reachable by domain.org:8081. Do I have to add some rewrite, proxy_redirect or other stuff?

Comment: did you get this working in the end?

Comment: No, sorry. I switched back to subdomains.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'overwritewebroot' [as described in the manual](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.1/admin_manual/configuration_server/config_sample_php_parameters.html#proxy-configurations). Edit your owncloud's 'config/config.php' and include:

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
    ...
    'overwritewebroot' => '/cloud',
    ...
);
```

Then owncloud will consider '/cloud/' as the base for any internal URL (e.g., images, styles, etc.).